Is the limit of bounded real-analytic functions also real-analytic?
Consider a sequence of functions that are defined on an open neighborhood $I \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\{f_n(x)\},\quad f_n:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$
Each $f_n(x)$ is real-analytic and bounded, $|f_n(x)| < A, \forall x\in I$, where $A$ is a constant independent of $n$.
Suppose the limit $f(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f_n(x)$ exists point-wise. My question is whether $f(x)$ is also a bounded real-analytic function?
Any comments and suggests on references are welcome!

Is $f(x)=|x|$ the pointwise limit of a sequence of real analytic functions on $(-1,1)$?

Thanks! Right, in my case $f_n(x)$ can also be continued to an analytic function in a neighborhood of $I$ for any finite $n$. But from Fourier series, even this condition is not strong enough for the conclusion to hold.

Stone-Weierstrass says any continuous function on $i$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of polynomials.

You get $f$ is bounded immediately from the fact that for each $x$ and $n$, $|f_n(x)|<A$. Taking the limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$, you get for each $x$, |f(x)|\leq A$.

$f(x)$ is bounded but not real-analytic.
Let $f_{n}(x)=\sqrt{x^2+\displaystyle\frac{1}{n^2}}$, then $f_n(x)\longrightarrow f(x)=\vert x\vert$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$(because $\vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert \le \displaystyle\frac{1}{n}%$), but $f(x)$ is obviously not derivative while $f_n(x)$ is real-analytic $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$.
